# How to pass the requested service id into the factory in Symfony 5?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony6, symfony-dependency-injection

My Symfony project's folders structure looks like this:

- src

  - API

    - V1

      - Systems

        - System1

          - Platform.php
        - System2

          - Platform.php
        - System3

          - Platform.php
        - SystemN
        - ..............

I want to create my services via [Multiple Service Definitions Using the Same Namespace](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#multiple-service-definitions-using-the-same-namespace).
My services.yaml:

```
services:
...........
    platform_names:
        namespace: App\API\V1\Systems\
        public: true
        resource: '../src/API/V1/Systems/*/Platform.php'
        tags: [ platform_name ]
        factory: '@App\API\V1\Systems\SystemsPlatformFactory'
        arguments:
            $platform_name: platform_name
```

And I get my service somewhere in my code:

```
$this->getContainer()->get('App\API\V1\Systems\System1\Platform');
```

Are there any ways to pass the requested service id (`System1`) into the factory `SystemsPlatformFactory`?
I tried

```
        arguments:
            $platform_name: platform_name
```

but that doesn't work.